# I need product Stock quantity from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

1. product_in (store all product QTY)

   ```
   Product Code(PK)     Description                QTY
   RS121102             SUITS                      100
   RS129985             SUITS                      100
   DF-C09               SHIRTS                     50
   AE-H05               SHIRTS                     50
   ```
2. product_out (store all products sold QTY)

   ```
   Product Code         Description                QTY
   RS121102             SUITS                      50
   AE-H05               SHIRTS                     10
   ```

I want result like below

```
Product Code         Description        Total Qty        Sold QTY
RS121102             SUITS                  100            50
RS129985             SUITS                  100            0
DF-C09               SHIRTS                 50             0
AE-H05               SHIRTS                 50             10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: SORRY FOR THE ANS SHOULD BE LIKE BELOW

Product Code         Description                QTY

RS121102             SUITS                      50  
RS129985             SUITS                      100 
DF-C09               SHIRTS                     50 
AE-H05               SHIRTS                     40 

it should show all the products which quantities has been sold or not has been sold

Comment: Is tagged as vb.net, but I can't see any vb code; is this a query you want to perform or something else?

Comment: Is the `QTY` column in the result supposed to be the value of `product_in.QTY` minus `product_out.QTY`?  Also, which part of this task are you having trouble with?  Are you having trouble writing a SQL command that will give you those results, or do you already have the command that works and you are having trouble executing it from VB.NET?  Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi @ StevenDoggart and @ Edward  , i have made question easy for you, and yes i am having trouble with generating SQL. could you help me please

Comment: Please alter your original question to show the correct values - how do you arrive at 100 Total Qty for DF-C09? Shouldn't it be 50?

Comment: @ElectricLlama I altered my question, sorry i was in hurry so could not noticed mistake. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT pi.ProductCode, pi.Description, pi.QTY AS TotalQty, 
ISNULL(po.QTY, 0) AS SoldQty
FROM product_in as pi
LEFT JOIN product_out as po
ON po.ProductCode = pi.ProductCode
```

That's asuming there aren't multiple records for each product in product_out.

Comment: This will only show records where there is a matching product. i.e. it will exclude RS129985 and DF-C09

Comment: @ElectricLlama - you're perfectly correct, missed that. Updated answer will return all records now.

Comment: this sql gave me following error  : WRONG NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS USED WITH FUNCTION IN QUERY EXPRESSION 'ISNULL(PO.QTY,0'--------- any solution ?

Comment: HEY THERE, -----THIS IS MY SQL>>>>>>  "SELECT ISNULL(qty,0 ) FROM product_in "---it still does not working, it keep saying me that --- WRONG NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS USED WITH FUNCTION IN QUERY EXPRESSION-----can anyone help me please-, I am using ms access as database

Comment: If you had worded your question correctly and given all of the information required then you would have had an answer to your question much sooner. In future please take time to consider what it is you need an what platforms you are using. Ms access isnull function works differently than mssql as it returns Boolean. You will need to use `IIF(ISNULL(Qty),0,Qty)`

Comment: thx @GJKH, i know i am new at this platform so bit mess up my question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductCode, Description, SUM(Total_QTY) AS Total_Qty, SUM(Sold_Qty) AS Sold_Qty
FROM 
(
     SELECT ProductCode, Description, QTY As Total_Qty, 0 As Sold_Qty
     from product_in
)
UNION ALL
(
     SELECT ProductCode, Description,  -QTY As Total_Qty, QTY As Sold_Qty
     from product_out
)
GROUP BY ProductCode, Description
```